# Where should I start laying a nail down hardwood floor in this room?

Tags: flooring, installation, hardwood

I am planning on installing a nail-down 2 1/4" hardwood floor in our great room. Each wall of the room has an "interruption", so I'm wondering where the best place to start is. One side has a large doorway into the entryway and a built-in bookshelf, another has huge sliding glass doors, another has a large brick fireplace, and the last wall has a doorway into the kitchen (see layout picture). Any idea on the best place to start? Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd start in front of the fireplace with a parallel line off the same wall. Work it out so that you have a reasonably-sized finisher strip at the wall.

You could also do the reverse and start at the bookshelves, but then you're travelling over your work for most of the job.

But this is a subjective question, so expect a variety of opinions.